# Anything to output xhtml?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've been using the HtmlAgilityPack to eat some XHTML documents, however, if I want to output my document as XHTML, it's not possible. Anyone have any other solutions other than the HtmlAgilityPack to transform XHTML?

I need to transform the document a bit, I'm assuming maybe this is easier using straight XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's an xhtml document, then it should be an xml document, so I'd say XSLT would be the more direct approach.